# Hiding custom toast behind keypad issue?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, uikit, toast

I want to show toast bottom of screen but, When keypad appears it is hiding. Please any one suggest me to solve. Thanks you.

Below is the code i am trying.

```
func displayToast(_ message : String) {
    guard let delegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate, let window = delegate.window else {
        return
    }
    if let toast = window.subviews.first(where: { $0 is UILabel && $0.tag == -1001 }) {
        toast.removeFromSuperview()
    }
    let toastView = UILabel()
    toastView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.7)
    toastView.textColor = UIColor.white
    toastView.textAlignment = .center
    toastView.font = UIFont(name: "Font-name", size: 17)
    toastView.layer.cornerRadius = 15
    toastView.clipsToBounds = true
    toastView.text = message
    toastView.numberOfLines = 0
    toastView.alpha = 0
    toastView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    toastView.tag = -1001
    let windowww = UIApplication.shared.windows[UIApplication.shared.windows.count - 1]
    windowww.addSubview(toastView)
    let horizontalCenterContraint: NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: toastView, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: windowww, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    let widthContraint: NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: toastView, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .width, multiplier: 1, constant: (self.frame.size.width-25) )
    let verticalContraint: [NSLayoutConstraint] = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-(>=200)-[toastView(==50)]-68-|", options: [.alignAllCenterX, .alignAllCenterY], metrics: nil, views: ["toastView": toastView])
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([horizontalCenterContraint, widthContraint])
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate(verticalContraint)
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: {
        toastView.alpha = 1
    }, completion: nil)
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(3), execute: {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: {
            toastView.alpha = 0
        }, completion: { finished in
            toastView.removeFromSuperview()
        })
    })
}
```